DAX SUMMARIZECOLUMNS why does FORMAT function cause blank rows from Date table to display
Partying with Contoso while studying DAX with sqlbi.com
Testing querys with daxstudio.
EVALUATE
SUMMARIZECOLUMNS(
    'Date'[Year],   
    'Date'[Month],  
    "Sales", Sales Amount]
)

Works with rows displayed and with no blank cells.
EVALUATE
SUMMARIZECOLUMNS(
    'Date'[Year],  
    'Date'[Month], 
    "Sales", FORMAT( [Sales Amount], "$#,0.00" )
)

Works and with those years with no associated data displayed also?
Why does FORMAT effect this way?


From DAX Guide (my bold):
https://dax.guide/format/
Return values
Scalar A single string value.
A string containing Value formatted as defined by Format string.
The result is always a string, even when the value is blank.
Blanks are being pruned in your first example. In your second example, a string is returned every row.
